# what is vapour pressure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

what exactly is **saturated vapour pressure** and **dew point**? how do we understand questions based on them and answer them?. I always get stuck whenever i try those type of questions.

Comment: So where have looked to find out yourself, what part of the explainations don't you follow. ? I know the Wikipedia page is not easy to read, but maybe try https://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/liquids/vpress.html

Comment: thank you :) i get the theory part but when it comes to questions i find them hard.

Comment: Welcome to physics :). This free PDF of solved problems might be helpful, esp. Page 252.    http://www.freepdfbook.com/schaums-outline-of-thermodynamics-for-engineers-pdf/

Answer (score 0):

In a jar, above the liquid surface vapour molecules are in random motion; they collide with each other and condense into liquid, and eventually an equilibrium would be established between vapour phase and liquid phase. Thus, both evaporation and condensation processes go on simultaneously.

*The pressure exerted by the vapour molecules on the surface of liquid in the jar at equilibrium is called vapour pressure.*

When a large mass of air containing dust particles in cooled below its dew point, the moisture in the air *condenses* on the surfaces of theses particles forming fine droplets. These droplets being colloidal in nature continue to float in air in for of mist.

Answer (score 0):

If a sealed container is partially full of water, the water will evaporate until air in the container is so saturated that as many molecules of water condense back into the liquid as evaporate out into the air.  At that point, there is equilibrium between liquid and gas.  The pressure inside the container when equilibrium is attained is [saturated vapor pressure](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/vappre.html).

If you heat the air inside the container, it will accept more molecules of water vapor, and pressure will rise.  If the air cools, it will accept less vapor, and pressure will fall.  Saturated vapor pressure varies with temperature.

[The dew point](http://www.livescience.com/43269-what-is-dew-point.html) is the temperature below which vapor in a closed container, or water vapor in the air above a field outdoors, condenses out of the air and deposits into the liquid in the container, or upon grass and plants in the field.  The dew point marks equilibrium between liquid and vapor.

The dew point is the temperature which indicates when saturation vapor pressure has been reached.  At the dew point, water vapor in the air is at saturation vapor pressure.

[This link](http://www.conservationphysics.org/atmcalc/atmoclc2.pdf) provides explanations of how moisture in the air is evaluated using saturated vapor pressure, the dew point, and relative humidity, which is the ratio of actual vapor pressure to saturation vapor pressure at a given temperature.  If you work through these equations and understand them thoroughly, you should have no trouble with questions.

Comment: Will the pressure of the liquid be just the vapor pressure or the sum of vapor and hydrostatic? In general when we talk about the pressure at equilibrium of liquid/vapor do we refer to vapor pressure?

Comment: @Anton   Hydrostatic pressure is "pressure exerted by a fluid *at equilibrium* at a given point within the fluid..."  For standing liquid, hydrostatic pressure *at equilibrium* is caused by gravity.

When talking about pressure at equilibrium of liquid/vapor, hydrostatic pressure would NOT be added to vapor pressure.  Hydrostatic pressure varies with depth of the liquid, whereas vapor pressure is the same all through the vapor.

Vapor pressure and hydrostatic pressure are different measures. When we talk about pressure at equilibrium of liquid/vapor, we refer to vapor pressure.